# tsibble with 2 keys (not hierarchy) having the week of the year as index

Tags: r, time-series, forecast

Can anyone give some suggestions as to how to construct a tsibble?

I have a dateset that has four original columns:  product, market, price, date
I want to construct a tsibble object.
I have the `key=id(product,market)` and 'year of the week' as index. 
then I can predict for each product in each market what should be the base line of price.

if you use `nycflights13::weather` data set, I can use `key=id(origin,year)` (here I do not have a market so use year to represent the market).

then have `idex=week(year+month+day)`. I can then combine the year, month, day column as date then calculate the `week()` then add year and week together as 'weekyear' and set up this as an index, then use `median(temp)` for that yearweek.
After this dataset reform I can have a tsibble able to predict next 2-4 weeks temp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you want to convert the `date` variable to `yearweek` class first. Can you do

```r
library(tsibble)
data %>%
  mutate(index = yearweek(date)) %>%
  as_tsibble(key = id(product, market), index = index)
```

Comment: I got this error:  > dft_ts <- dft %>% 
+   mutate(index = yearweek(date)) %>%
+   as_tsibble(key = id(artikel_id, market), index = index)
Error: A valid tsibble must have distinct rows identified by key and index.
Please use `duplicates()` to check the duplicated rows.

Comment: this works: dft_ts <- dft %>% 
  mutate(yw=yearweek(date)) %>% 
  group_by(yw,artikel_id,market) %>% 
  summarise(avg_w_pric=mean(med_pric)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  as_tsibble(key = id(artikel_id, market), index = yw)